# Problema trabajando con arreglos y objetos en JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un curso introductorio al desarrollo web.
Actualmente estoy resolviendo el siguiente ejercicio y agradecería contar con su ayuda:

Debés crear una función llamada `arregloDeObjetos` que reciba un número como parámetro y devuelva un arreglo de objetos que tengan una propiedad llamada `valor` que contenga el valor del número y sus anteriores.
Ejemplo:
arregloDeObjetos(5) debe retornar [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}, {valor: 4}, {valor: 5}]
arregloDeObjetos(3) debe retornar [{valor: 1}, {valor: 2}, {valor: 3}]

Dicho esto, les paso el código que escribi:

```
function arregloDeObjetos(n){
    let newArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        newArray.push("valor:" + i)
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Si uso esta formula en la consola, con 5 como parametro, el resultado es: `['valor:0', 'valor:1', 'valor:2', 'valor:3', 'valor:4', 'valor:5'].`

Entiendo que la lógica la estoy pensando bien, pero me están faltando las {} en cada elemento, para representar a los objetos..

¿Qué es lo que le está faltando a mi código?

Pensé en poner   `newArray.push("valor:" + i)` con unas llaves dentro del parentesis que tiene el "valor:" + i, pero el Visual Studio me da error.. asi que no se qué hacer

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Esta bien en tu lógica lo único que te hace falta es agregar el objeto ejemplo: 
```newArray.push({valor: i+1})```

Comment: Entendido. Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Hermanos seamos un poco humildes `ser||!ser`... Si el código no hace lo que debe entonces la lógica está mal

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estás concatenando `"valor:" + i`, y eso no crea un objeto, sino un String. Insisto en el concepto: no se trata de imprimir llaves, eso no hace más objeto al valor de retorno, para más detalles, por favor lee [esta referencia de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Ahora de lleno a la solución, que es muy simple, y se trata de crear objetos en lugar de concatenar (es decir, usar `{valor:i}`):

```javascript
function arregloDeObjetos(n) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    newArray.push({valor: i});
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(arregloDeObjetos(5));
console.log(typeof arregloDeObjetos(5));
```

Te aconsejo leer la referencia (y alguna cosa más), porque hay muchos conceptos atrás de esto y te falta afirmar algunos que son de base.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Si.. estoy haciendo un curso introductorio.. y hasta ahora practique bastante arrays pero recién estoy empezando a trabajar con objetos.. asi que tengo muchas dudas, jaja, gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Lo edité porque ibas de 0 a n y debías ir de 1 a n. El resto está igual.